# Is FTP publishing from Visual Studio 2010 secure?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, security, ftp, publish

I noticed some strange activity on a server after I had been using FTP to publish for a few days...

> **edit:** added this to give an example, skip over this quote if you have no idea
>
> Basically when I got back an error message from my app in the form of
> HTML, my browser was trying to find a favicon at this URL:
> http://w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec/

I am pretty sure that FTP sends passwords in plain text but I wasn't sure if Visual Studio had any other mechanism for securing this, or if I need to set something on the server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

FTPS is supported in the "Publish Web Site" dialog. Enter the address as ftps rather than ftp or http and if the site is set up for FTPS it should work. What is not supported as I can see is opening a Web site with FTPS rather than plain ftp.

Answer (score 3):

FTP will send your credentials in plain text so in theory, your credentials could have been intercepted and reused in transit. Unfortunately Visual Studio doesn't support SFTP or FTPS so your best bet is to publish from Visual Studio using Web Deploy which will connect over HTTPS if publishing to IIS7.